# Exit function for exit button

Tags: java, jframe

How to implement the exit function in my "EXIT LAHH!" button after I click it? I am not sure what codes to use.
I tried the addActionListener but I not so sure what is needed to add into the ()..

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class TestButton1 {
private Frame F;
private Button B;
private Button C;

public TestButton1(){
F = new Frame("Welcome!");
B = new Button("Press Me! \nSo that, you can genarate OUTPUT result at the CONSOLE");
B.setActionCommand("ButtonPressed");
C = new Button("EXIT LAHHH!");
C.setActionCommand("ButtonPressed");

//javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE }

public void launchFrame(){
B.addActionListener(new mainclass());   

//Allow user to use the (X) close button
F.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
            System.exit(0);
      }
    });


F.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
F.add(B);
F.add(C);


F.setBackground(Color.green);
B.setBackground(Color.pink);
C.setBackground(Color.white);
F.setSize(600, 70);
F.setVisible(true);     
}    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestButton1 guiApp = new TestButton1();
    guiApp.launchFrame();
}  }
```

Comment: Anonymous inner class implementing `actionPerformed` would do, similar to what you did with the `WindowListener`

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

C.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to close Frame?
[Here is tutorial](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/)

Try: `frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, no where do I see "your exit function" so I shall assume you mean `System.exit(0);` by that.

I see you've implemented a WindowListener here:

```
F.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
        System.exit(0);
  }
});
```

which essentially adds a anonymous inner class as a listener. Using the same concept, we can add a **ActionListener** to a button.

Consider the following:

```
C.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

The `ActionListener` executes when the button is pressed and released, executing the code within the `actionPerformed()` method.

In addition, you may also replace `System.exit(0);` within the "button exit code" with `setVisible(false);`

Like such:

```
C.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

In my opinion thats a more elegant solution, closing the frame before ending the program.